# Searching in Dash

Tags: unity, unity-dash, search, filename

What are the characters which the Dash search uses to split filenames into words?

I mean, if you have a file `some random.txt`, the dash will show if you enter either `'some'` or `'random'`. But what if I had `SomeRandom.txt` or `some_random.txt` or `some.random.txt`?

Which characters are considered as word splitters?

Answer (score 0):

For `find` command it depends on the switches you provide for it, if no special search switches are issued it will do a general pattern match, as in part of the file/folder matches your search it will show up.

for more info you can read in the link about the `find` command

[Find Command](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_find.htm)